# Output of groups different then id

Tags: linux, centos6, nis

I'm sure this is something simple, but I can't for the life of me figure out what is going on.

We are using NIS (haven't had a chance to migrate to LDAP) and for some reason the groups aren't being displayed correctly.

```
[scott.adair@tor-admin01 ~]$ groups
pfa-admin
```

But when I search based on my username, it returns correctly

```
[scott.adair@tor-admin01 ~]$ groups scott.adair
scott.adair : pfa-admin it-admin
```

This is the same for the id command as well. This seems to work fine for local users (root), but not for any of my NIS accounts.

I can use the newgrp command to switch to the it-admin group, but that seems like a bit of hack.

Any ideas?

Comment: what does 'id' command show? both groups or only one?

Comment: Shows only one, unless I specify the username then it shows both.

Comment: Have you logged out and logged in after you added new groups? id+username takes these groups from /etc/group or NIS but just id gives you the current groups that were added when you logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the /etc/nssiwtch.conf and changed

```
passwd:     compat
shadow:     compat
group:      compat
```

to

```
passwd:     files nis
shadow:     files nis
group:      files nis
```

Now all the groups are listed when I run the id or groups commands.

```
[scott.adair@tor-admin01 ~]$ id
uid=6100(scott.adair) gid=5000(pfa-admin) groups=5000(pfa-admin),5001(it-admin)

[scott.adair@tor-admin01 ~]$ groups
pfa-admin it-admin
```